# ajuda com manipulacao de tempo em Time com php

Tags: php, time

Tenho um código onde armazeno no banco de dados a hora da postagem no formato time e quero mostra a hora da postagem no formato "postado a 1 dia" por exemplo, a hora, minutos e segundos ja consegui, gostaria de ajuda para colocar dias, meses e anos, se tem um jeito de fazer sem ter que pegar por exemplo a cada 24 hora um dia.

```
 public function postTime($date) {

    $time = time() - $date;
    $h = floor($time / 3600);
    $time -= $h * 3600;
    $m = floor($time / 60);
    $time -= $m * 60;
    $s = $time;

    if ($h > 0) {
        $this->txt = $h == 1 ? "A uma hora" : "A ## horas";
        $this->txt = preg_replace("/#([#]+)/i", $h, $this->txt);
    }
    if ($m > 0) {
        if ($h > 0) {
            $this->txt .= " e ";
        }
        $this->txt .= $m == 1 ? " A um minuto" : "A ## minutos" ;
        $this->txt = preg_replace("/#([#]+)/i", $m, $this->txt);
    }
    if ($h == 0 && $m == 0) {
        if ($s == 0) {
            echo "Agora";
        }
        $this->txt = $s == 1 ? "A um segundo" : "A ## segundos";
        $this->txt = preg_replace("/#([#]+)/i", $s, $this->txt);
    }
    echo $this->txt;
}
```

}

Comment: Há uma série de coisas que precisamos de saber. O que você já fez? Tem algum código de exemplo? Qual é o formato da data que você está salvando no banco?

Comment: A horas estou salvando no formato time();